# How can I add insert and delete buttons provided by UITableView setEditing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add insert and delete buttons for individual cells in a table view.

The following code is working fine for deleting for insertion also I want the button not in navigation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    card = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"card1",@"Card2",@"card3",@"card4",nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;


    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [card removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the edit button in navigation bar get rid of this line:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Then create your own button and with its action call `[tableview setEditing:]` yourself.

To enable delete buttons for specific cells and not others, implement the tableview delegate method:

```
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

And return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for any rows you don't want to show a delete button in edit mode, and `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for ones that you do want to.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what is it that you are looking for? You want an edit button to be displayed in the navigation bar?

Seems to me you should already have that:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Comment: not in navigation bar the i want insert and delete button on each cell.